# Database returning 0 for results less than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Database that determines different values based on a label. Where the label determines whether it's an exempted value or not. For instance, 2 = non exempted and 3 = exempted. If I run a query my results look something like this

```
|Name  |EXEMPT VALUE|NON EXEMPT VALUE|Total Value|
|X     |100.00      |200.00          |300.00     |  
|Y     |0.00        |4.50            |4.50       |
```

The value of the Exempt value for Y is actually a number less than one, 0.30.
I did not create the database so I had no control of the datatypes of the values. The datatype is numeric, would that be the cause of my query returning the value as 0.00? Should I cast the numbers as another datatype to get the correct result. My query is below.

```
    SELECT
    NAME
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 2 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS 'NON EXEMPT VALUE'
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3 THEN TOTAL_VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS  'EXEMPT VALUE'
   SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) AS 'TOTAL VALUE'
   FROM ORDER_ACCOUNT JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE
   WHERE ORDER_ACCOUNT.DATE BETWEEN 'M/D/YEAR' AND 'M/D/YEAR'
   GROUP BY NAME
   ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Comment: Forget your query for a while, play about with adding INTs to NUMERICs. This'll highlight what you're seeing.

Comment: well all my datatype are numerics, there are no ints in the query I'm running. What I'm questioning is why is that happening if numeric has the precision of a decimal.

Comment: `ELSE 0 END` - There's an INT

Comment: Ah yes, of course! How ridiculous. So how do I go about that if I remove it, the value is Null, would I cast/convert my Case?

Comment: Would `ELSE 0.0` work?

Comment: But numeric is a higher precedence than int so it would still use the numeric datatype. You can however just add a decimal point to your 0. to force it to numeric.

Comment: It doesn't work if I add a decimal to the zero

Comment: Why in the case you `SUM(TOTAL_VALUE)` but in the total you `SUM(VALUE)`

Comment: None of your daa has an exemption status of 3.

Comment: There is no `ON` clausule on your `JOIN` and no dates on the `BETWEEN` range

Comment: I did not include it in the code here, but in my query that I'm running the ON clause is there. `On Order_Account.RID = ACCOUNT_INVOICE.ORDERID`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `* 1.0` and `ELSE 0.0`

And use `VALUE` on each `SUM`

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 2 THEN TOTAL_VALUE * 1.0
             ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'NON EXEMPT VALUE',
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3 THEN TOTAL_VALUE * 1.0
              ELSE 0.0 END) AS 'EXEMPT VALUE',
    SUM(TOTAL_VALUE) AS 'TOTAL VALUE'
FROM ORDER_ACCOUNT JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE
WHERE ORDER_ACCOUNT.DATE BETWEEN 'M/D/YEAR' AND 'M/D/YEAR'
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Comment: No it just added an extra zero. Also, to my earlier sum, that was a typo

Comment: try `SELECT VALUE FROM ... WHERE EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3`

Comment: As stated above, there is no VALUE column, that was a typo. If I `SUM(TOTAL_VALUE)' I get the Non-Exempt value plus the Exempt Value, I wanted two columns that would show those two values as well.

Comment: Then fix the question. But still check for `SELECT Name, TOTAL_VALUE WHERE EXEMPTIONSTATUS = 3 ... DATE ...`  but without group by. Because really doesnt make sense.

Comment: btw, `* 1.0 `doesnt add a `0` convert the number to float, so you should try that too.